# Как добавить кнопку плюс в область заголовка приложения Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, gui, разметка

Как добавить кнопку плюс в область как на картинке?

[image]

Главная особенность в том, что кнопка должна находиться там, где находится название приложения, в зелёной области.

Если можно, то желательно на kotlin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Привожу код на обоих языках, так как не уверена на 100% в своих познаниях Kotlin. Надеюсь, это окажется полезным.

В папке `res/menu` необходимо создать файл разметки меню, например `mainmenu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_plus"
        android:icon="@drawable/yourplusdrawable"
        android:showAsAction="always"/> 
</menu>
```

А в классе Вашей Activity нужно добавить метод (если его ещё нет), в котором прописать добавление этого меню на панель.

Java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Kotlin:

```
fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu:Menu):Boolean {
  val inflater = getMenuInflater()
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu)
  return true
}
```

Чтобы обрабатывать нажатия на элемент меню, добавьте метод:

Java:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_plus) {
       // тут что-то делать
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Kotlin:

```
fun onOptionsItemSelected(item:MenuItem):Boolean {
  val id = item.getItemId()
  if (id == R.id.action_plus)
  {
    // тут что-то делать
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Этот вариант действительно работает, но выглядит как костыль, ведь я добавляю не кнопку на прямую, а один из пунктов меню. Есть ли какой-то более простой вариант?

Comment: Это самый обычный способ для таких целей) Из других вариантов - разве что создать свой ActionBar со своей разметкой... Но вряд ли это будет более простой вариант

Comment: @llollcat зачем вам этот плюс там? костылем кажется это желание, есть рекомендации от Google

Comment: @Style-7 Вы о чём? Посмотрите приложение Action Blocks, которое было сделано Google. Там есть кнопка помощи, которая находится справа вверху, притом единственная. Это аналогично моей ситуации. Так о каких рекомендациях вы говорите? Плавающая кнопка мне не подходит, если что.

Comment: @llollcat это вы о чем, вам дали решение, а вы его называете костылем